# How to find a key that matches two or more unique column entries?

Tags: mysql

For example if I have a table "professor" and a table "transcript" which stores the name classes that have been taught.  I want to find professors who have taught two or more different classes. My code returns professors who have taught two or more classes, but doesn't check if they are unique.
What should I add to check if the classes are unique.

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, COUNT(*)
FROM professor AS prof
INNER JOIN transcript T
ON prof.pid = T.pid
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(*) >=2;
```

Comment: If there are 2 professor with same name, you need group by prof.pid instead. and count(distinct class_id) will help you find out the unique classes

Comment: If you are doing this in reality, you can use `count(distinct lectureid)`. If that is a homework question, you might have to rely on joins, because that kind of code it is not always allowed.

Comment: Awesome man thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    name, class_count
FROM 
    professor prof
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT pid, count(*) as class_count FROM transcript GROUP BY pid) as T
ON 
    prof.pid=T.pid
WHERE
    class_count >= 2
```

This query however needs that the transcript table has UNIQUE index on both **pid** and an identifier of the transcript record (ie **class**) -- to make sure that they are not duplicated.